# How to use encrypted password in python email

Tags: python, email, encryption, sendmail

I want to have Python send a mail automatically after certain events occur. In my script I have to enter a password. Is there any way to encrypt my password and use it in this script?

Please give an example as I am not an expert in python. I have seen few answers on this topic but those aren't discussed completely, just some hints are given.

Comment: Well if you have an encrypted password and a script that is able to decrypt it, then any attacker would get access to the clear text password as well.

Comment: perhaps your sending script also knows something else about the destination person that you  can use to encrypt the password, eg the last time they logged in, or their street address, or their phone number.

Comment: I'd propose using the keyring. For a real nice email client, you can use [yagmail](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail) as [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31839983/1575066) states below (full disclose: I'm the developer)

Answer (score 5):

The script needs the password in plain text to send the email. You could encrypt it, but then you also have to provide a way to decrypt it on the fly.

Let me illustrate with some pseudo code.

Right now you have something like this:

```
password = 'supersecret'
send_mail(password=password)
```

If you encrypt the password it would look something like this:

```
encrypted_password = 'kasdjhfkauedsjflh'
encryption_key = 'allyourbase'
send_mail(password=decrypt(encrypted_password, encryption_key)
```

As you can see, it doesn't really make any difference.

Comment: In this case, someone who access the file, can also decrept the password ?

Comment: Exactly. The is no way to prevent that.

Comment: You can use the keyring approach by [yagmail](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail) :)

Answer (score 3):

Encryption basically tries to rely on *one* (and only one) secret.
That is, one piece of data that is known to those who want to communicate but not to an attacker.

In the past attempts have been made to e.g. (also) keep the encryption algorithm/implementation secret, but if that implementation is widely used (in a popular cryptosystem) those attempts have generally fared poorly.

*In general* that one secret is the password. So that even if the attacker knows the encryption algorithm, he cannot decrypt the traffic if he doesn't know the password.

As others have shown, encrypting a password and giving a script the means to decrypt it is *futile* if the attacker can get hold of the script. It's like a safe with the combination of the lock written on the door.

On the other hand as long as you can keep your script secret, the key in it is secret as well.

So if you restrict the permissions of your script such that only the root/administrator user can read or execute it, the only way for an attacker to access it is to have cracked the root/administrator account. In which case you've probably already lost.

**The biggest challenges in cases like these are operational**.
Here are some examples of things that you should *not* do;

- Make the script readable by every user.
- Store the script where it can by read be a publicly accessible web-server.
- Upload it to github or any other public hosting service.
- Store it in an unencrypted backup.

**Update:** You should also consider how the script uses the password. If it sends the password over the internet in cleartext, you don't have much security anyway.

Comment: What do you think of [yagmail](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail#username-and-password)'s keyring approach?

Comment: @PascalvKooten From a cursory reading of the code, it doesn't seem to enforce TLS? Doesn't that mean it sends the password as plain text?

Comment: Whenever I do the login, it has smtp.starttls() on... isn't that it?

Comment: @PascalvKooten Yes, but that is only called `if self.starttls is not None`, and `None` is the default when the `SMTP` class is initialized.

Comment: Which version are you on? `smtp_starttls = True` is the default for as long as I can remember... Wait a minute, are you talking smtplib or yagmail?

Comment: @PascalvKooten I just looked at the yagmail repo, not smtplib.

Comment: It says `starttls = True` at [source, line 42](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail/blob/master/yagmail/yagmail.py#L42)

Answer (score 2):

My way is to use the keyring, simply using [yagmail](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail) you can have passwordless scripts by using the keyring (full disclose: I'm the developer of yagmail).

E.g. to send an email:

```
import yagmail
yag = yagmail.SMTP()
yag.send(contents = ["See picture below", "/local/path/to/img.png"])
```

To get this done, first install (below) and then register your email into the keyring once by using:

```
yagmail.register('myemail', 'mypass')
```

If you also put a `.yagmail` file in your home (`~`) folder containing your username, you can use yagmail.SMTP() in your script and safely login.

Install:

```
pip install yagmail   # python 2
pip3 install yagmail  # python 3
```

Ironically, I also have made [gittyleaks](https://github.com/kootenpv/gittyleaks), you can use it to discover username/passwords/email in a git repo, including all history :)

Comment: It seems to work only with gmail? `SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, '5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials f42sm3207250lji.2 - gsmtp')`. Or Have I failed to provide some info?